# Hitting a bad directory causes the application pool to restart

Tags: asp.net, iis

The application pool of IIS is restarting whenever I hit a bad path/directory of my application.

http://localhost/Test/Web/ exists and works fine. But when I try to hit a directory that does not exist e.g. http://localhost/Test/NonExistingDirectory , it displays a 404 page and application pool shuts down.

Event viewer shows the following details:

```
Event code: 1002 
Event message: Application is shutting down. Reason: Configuration changed. 
Event time: 8/3/2016 6:54:29 PM 
Event time (UTC): 8/3/2016 1:24:29 PM 
Event ID: bbeb7e9b4d8f4524b34e7172f67e4e21 
Event sequence: 5 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 50004
```

Is this(application pool shutting down) an expected behavior or something weird is happening?

Comment: I think you need to have latest IE and also turn off anti-virus and also check which application pool is your webpage local host is using.Then restart the application pool or create new one and assign the localhost to the newly created app pool.Hope this helps :)

Comment: What kind of web application is running on the server? it seems like there is some error logging written to a web.config file, which causes the restart